# How to host a React app in Nodejs without using Express?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express

I know the standard way is to use Express, but i was wondering how i could achieve this without having to use it. I already know how to serve html files using http/https in a common website (without a frontend framework) through nodejs, but when i tried to do the same with index.html from React app, it wouldn't work. I think it's important to mention that i am using react-router. I searched a lot about this but every tutorial would use Express, so i couldn't find help in google.

Here's how i would do with plain html:

```
const server = http.createServer( async (req, res) => {

res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

const requestUrl = url.parse(req.url);
let completePath = requestUrl.pathname;
let path = completePath.split('/').slice(1)[0];

let fileContent;

if(path == "")
    path = "index.html";

try{
    fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path);
    res.end(fileContent, 'utf-8');
}
catch(err){
    console.log("File not found: " + path);
    if(path != "favicon.ico"){
        res.statusCode = 404;
        fileContent = fs.readFileSync("404.html");
        res.end(fileContent);
    }
}


});
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I know the standard way is to use Express" Its not! Most times it's from a CDN. Express is for your API

Comment: Any Webserver ie nginx should be able to serve static files. You don't need a backend do ya?

Comment: Please, use a proper webserver instead of your "standard way" because it's buggy, insecure and not very performant. 1) `favicon.ico` just hangs, it never returns a response. 2) Your server doesn't return the correct `Content-Type` headers for non-HTML files so most parts of the website won't load properly. 3) Subfolders are not working. 4) Users can currently access _any_ file including `package.json` or your `server.js` itself. 5) Your file access is blocking the event loop so no other requests can be served while one of them is reading the file. - You should really consider Caddy/nginx/etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i eventually got it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('http');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;


const server = https.createServer( async (req, res) => {

    res.statusCode = 200;
    let root = "./build";

    let path = root + req.url;

    let fileContent;

    if(path == root + "/")
        path = path + "index.html";

    try{
        fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path);
        res.end(fileContent, 'utf-8');
    }
    catch(err){
        if(req.url != "/favicon.ico"){
            fileContent = fs.readFileSync(root + "/index.html");
            res.end(fileContent);
        }
    }

});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on " + port);
});
```

as opposed to Express version:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// this throws everything to the user
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/build"));

// this redirects everything to index.html
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/build/index.html");
});


app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on " + port);
});
```

Comment: Your code has the same issues I described in my comment on your question, plus an additional even more severe path traversal vulenarbility (try accessing `http://localhost:3000/../../../../../../../../etc/passwd` on Linux/Mac or `http://localhost:3000/../../../../../../../../Windows/system.ini` on Windows - by the way the latter works even with your first code if you use `%5C` (encoded `\ `) instead of `/`)...

Comment: Please, read up on how to serve static website files properly with a webserver that's built for that task. Any basic file server will do, all you need "extra" is an option to tell it to serve `index.html` for non-existing routes.

Comment: ...ok correction, the `../../` thing doesn't work luckily because node.js filters it, and `%5C` doesn't work because you don't decode URL entities. But `curl 'http://localhost:3000/..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Windows/system.ini'` works on Windows still.